Help Installing NVIDIA 390 driver on Ubuntu
efsandino@efsandino-laptop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-390
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-390 is already the newest version (390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 114 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up nvidia-dkms-390 (390.157-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-390.157 DKMS files...
Deleting module nvidia-390.157 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new nvidia-390.157 DKMS files...
Building for 6.5.0-28-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.5.0-28-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.157/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-390 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-390 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-390:
 nvidia-driver-390 depends on nvidia-dkms-390 (<= 390.157-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-390 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-390 depends on nvidia-dkms-390 (>= 390.157); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-390 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-390 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-28-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-390
 nvidia-driver-390
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


What version of Ubuntu?

the version is Ubuntu 22.04
